# How to limit the subset of git commands that zsh will auto-complete (with tab)?

Tags: git, shell, command-line, zsh, tab-completion

I have a combination of:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

and

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
```

It actually allows for a great amount of integration between git and zsh's tab completion. Too much in fact. How do I limit the set of commands, so that `git che(TAB)` will expand to `checkout`, and not to a choice between `checkout` and `checkout-index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a lot of fine control, but this should work:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' commands base
```

However, this may rely upon recent fixes to the _git completion (in particular, a quoting fix) so you might want to grab the latest _git definition from CVS (or local git mirror):

http://zsh.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zsh/zsh/Completion/Unix/Command/_git

Available words to go after 'commands': all base additional useful interoperability ancillary internal